# Access a local variable of a function of a module in another module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a module with the following code in a module named pytest1.py:

```
def addcount():
    counter = 1
    for x in range(10):
        counter += 1
        if counter == 5:
            count = counter
    print(count)

addcount()
```

I want to access 'count' variable in another module named pytest2.py 
I tried :

```
import pytest1 as p


print(p.addcount.count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return the variable `count` when `addcount()` is called such as,

```
def addcount():
    counter = 1
    for x in range(10):
        counter += 1
        if counter == 5:
            count = counter
    return count
```

then call the addcount and store the variable returned,

```
import pytest1 as p

a=p.addcount()
print(a)
```

Hope this helps you, let me know if anything is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` variable isn't created until `addcount()` is called, and it only exists during execution of "pytest1.py", so you can't import it directly. You should have `addcount()` return `count` instead of printing it to console.